# Using the property "onto" in a proof

Tags: general-topology, functions

**Definition (Minimal Open Set)**: A nonempty open set $U$ of $X$ is said to be a *minimal open* set if and only if any open set which is contained in $U$ is $∅$ or $U$.

**Definition (Minimal continuous map)**: Let $X$ and $Y$ be the topological spaces. A map $f: X → Y$ is called *minimal continuous* if $f^{-1}(M)$ is an open set in $X$ for every minimal open set $M$ in $Y$.

**Definition (T$_{min}$ Space)**: A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be *T$_{min}$* space if every nonempty proper open subset of $X$ is minimal open set.

**Theorem:** Let : $f:X\rightarrow Y$  be a minimal continuous, onto map and Y be a T$_{min}$ space.
Then $f$ is continuous.

**Proof:** Let be $f$ a minimal continuous, onto map. Let $N$ be any nonempty proper open set in $Y$. By
hypothesis, $Y$ is T$_{min}$ space. It follows that $N$ is a minimal open set in $Y$. Since $f$ is minimal continuous, $f^{-1}(N)$ is an open in X. Therefore is a continuous.

Now, where did we use that $f$ is onto? I think if $f$ were not be onto, the proof would still work.

Comment: what is a $T_{\text{min}}$ space? the definition? And a minimal continuous $f$?

Comment: I am going to add these definitions right now.

Comment: A quick search on Google shows an article in the Pacific Journal of Mathematics called _Minimal $T_0$-spaces and mininimal $T_D$-spaces. I don't know if that's what you mean but even if it were, you should provide the definitions.

Comment: I have added the definitions.

Comment: It seems that you are right: being onto is not necessary. However I wonder where did you find these definitions, since a $T_{min}$ space is simply a topological space with at most four open sets. It's not an interesting definition.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. On Minimal Open Sets and Maps in Topological
Spaces

Comment: @Crostul I agree, see my answer.

Comment: Regarding your question I'd say yes, the onto property isn't necessary. But I'm not sure about what a minimal space is, or more precisely, its applications. Such spaces have really few open sets. For instance, minimal open sets must be disjoint, and the union is the total space. Thus, every minimal space should consist of two connected components, each of them having the trivial topology as a subspace topology. PS: I was typing on my phone and I didn't realise others said exactly the same as I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show that $f$ is continuous, we need to show that *every* open subset $O$ of $Y$ has an open inverse image.

But $f^{-1}[Y]=X$ for any function $f:X \to Y$, by definition and $X$ is always open in $X$. Likewise $f^{-1}[\emptyset] = \emptyset$ always and $\emptyset$ is always open in $X$, so the open sets $O=\emptyset,Y$ have been taken care of.

So we only need to consider $O$ with $\emptyset \neq O \neq Y$. But then indeed as $Y$ is $T_{\text{min}}$ by definition $O$ is minimal open in $Y$ and then as $f$ is "minimal continuous" we also have  that $f^{-1}[O]$ is open in $X$.

So always $f^{-1}[O]$ is open for all $O \subseteq Y$ open. So $f$ is continuous.

**I don't see where ontoness would be needed**, maybe the author thought it would be needed for $f^{-1}[Y]=X$ but this is not the case! $f^{-1}[Y] = \{x \in X\mid f(x)\in Y\} = X$ as $f$ maps $X$ into $Y$ by definition. Ontoness is saying $f[X]=Y$.

FWIW: I think these concepts of $T_{\text{min}}$ spaces and minimally continuous maps are a bit trivial and unnatural. There are hardly interesting natural examples. Nothing in "real life" fulfills it. The indiscrete space and some trivial variations thereof. Nothing worth bothering about. My 2 cts.

Comment: These $T_{min}$ spaces have at most four open sets. If there are two non trivial open sets $U,V$, then $U \cup V = X$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$. Hence the topology is simply $\{ \emptyset , X, U, X \setminus U \}$. Otherwise the topology is $\{ \emptyset , X, U \}$ or $\{ \emptyset , X \}$. Not very interesting.

Comment: @Crostul that's what I meant with "indiscrete of trivial variations thereof". It seems that someone is desperate to publish some paper somewhere crappy.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. @Henno Brandsma

Comment: @Crostul Indeed a [crappy paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267962925_On_Minimal_Open_Sets_and_Maps_in_Topological_Spaces) filled with trivialities. I rejected a lot of similar papers when I was still doing referee work back at uni.